# Model seems to be over-predicting on the x axis (ggeffects)

Tags: r, ggplot2, lme4

I seem to be having a problem with my model over fitting on the x axis. This is leading to the trend line beginning in a strange place. I am looking for a reason why this might be ocurring?

```
data = read.csv('TotMaxSize.csv')
```

Data:

```
    structure(list(Column1 = 1:6, yrblock15 = c(2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 
2004L, 2004L, 2004L), circleID = 1:6, ThreeYearRain = c(748.9863518, 
744.4805429, 748.6081666, 747.5941999, 746.3382951, 740.9514718
), time = c(5.270172597, 4.270172617, 3.348596103, 3.019112219, 
2.905252281, 2.773856447), claylake = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.01, 0), 
    spinsandplain = c(99.53, 90.39, 50.7, 63.8, 73.65, 82.73), 
    TotMaxSize = c(2058.592458, 936.2305886, 1652.692998, 2162.200459, 
    1062.143104, 1863.051545)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Loaded packages:

```
library(ggplot2);library(lme4);library(ggeffects);library(dplyr)
```

Model:

```
m3 <- lmer(TotMaxSize~log(time)+spinsandplain+ThreeYearRain+claylake+ThreeYearRain*log(time)+(1|circleID),na.action=na.fail,data=data,REML=FALSE)
```

Plot:

```
d <-ggpredict(m3, terms = "time[exp]")
d <- rename(d, "time" = x, "TotMaxSize" = predicted)
ggplot(d, aes(time, TotMaxSize)) + 
  geom_point(data = data, colour = "orangered3") + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high), alpha = .1) +
  geom_line(size = 2, colour = "black") +
  theme_bw()
```

It produces this:

[image]

If I limit axes it produces this:

[image]

But the trend line seems to start in a weird place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `ggpredict(m3, terms = "time[exp]")`, i.e. you exponentiate `time`. I assume time cannot be negative, so the minimum value would be `exp(0)`, which is `1` (just a guess).

Furthermore, if you're interested in a change over time, I would probably not use `log(time)` in the model, but rather use `log(TotMaxSize)`, or use a logarithmic transformation of the y-axis (`scale_y_log10()`). Is `log(time)` intentional?

An alternative would be to create a vector with exponentiated values, and add the first values manually:

```r
v <- c(0, 0.5, exp(seq(0, 10, .5)))
ggpredict(m3, terms = "time[v]")
```

Here's a toy-example:

```r
library(lme4)
#> Loading required package: Matrix
library(ggeffects)
library(ggplot2)
data("sleepstudy")
sleepstudy$Days <- sleepstudy$Days + 1
m <- lmer(Reaction ~ log(Days) + (1 + Days | Subject), data = sleepstudy)

## not starting at "0"

plot(ggpredict(m, "Days [exp]")) + 
  xlim(c(0, 25)) +
  coord_cartesian()
#> Warning: Removed 7 row(s) containing missing values (geom_path).
```

[image]

```r
## starting at "0"

v <- c(0.1, 0.5, exp(seq(0, 5, .5)))

plot(ggpredict(m, "Days [v]")) + 
  xlim(c(0, 25)) +
  coord_cartesian()
#> Warning: Removed 4 row(s) containing missing values (geom_path).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>